# Intellij 12 and Tomcat: Debugging into the source of dependent jars

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

This problem is now really frustrating me more than ever as I am fully dependent on the debugger to identify a difficult bug. This is my environment

- Web application written in Java
- Packaged and deployed as war file in Tomcat 7 and running in Windows
- IntelliJ 12, with remote debugging to Tomcat

I have to navigate and set break points quite often in the code contained in the jar files of my web module (not part of the project). I checked out the needed source code of the jar files locally and "attached" the code, but I have the following problems

1. Quite often, I cannot see the source code - I just see the method signature. This happens sometimes after a redeploy, but sometimes even otherwise. Even after several attempts to attach the source, I cannot see the source code
2. Sometimes even if I see the source code(ie, attach was successful), the debugger behaves in a funny way, ie, it looks like even though the source I see is the right one, IntelliJ is running code through somewhere else. So I miss break points, sometimes goes through the wrong branch of an if-else etc.

I tried invalidating the cache and restarted, but in vain. When I looked at the Intellij system cache, I was surprised to see several very old copies of the library and even several copies of the same snapshot of the same library, all in the cache. So invalidating cache doesn't seem to have any effect in getting rid of stale copies in the system cache.

Can anyone else who had one or more of the problems that I have please shed some light on how they have solved these? Also what exactly happens when "Invalidate cache" is performed? Can I safely get rid of all the old jar files?

Comment: It looks like you are not attaching the right source files to your jars. If you're using a dependency management tool like Maven or Gradle, IntelliJ will correctly download and attach source code to the jars. I recommend you try that before starting to mess around with the IntelliJ guts.

Comment: I can verify that the source location is correct, but sometimes when the dependent source is changed and the project is rebuilt, i have the problem mentioned, even though the attached source is updated.